# PHP Casting Error

Tags: php, casting

```
<?php
isInt("4");
isInt("Test");
function isInt($id){
    echo $id." ".(int)$id;
    if($id == (int)$id)echo "True.<br />";
    else echo "False.<br />";   
}

?>
```

The output results in:

```
4 4 True.
Test 0 True.
```

You'll notice the 2nd results in true, which by the output, it should echo false.

I realize there is a built in function in php is_int().

I also realize that in the if statement if I put a 3rd equals sign: `if($id === (int)$id)` then it will return false for the 2nd one, but it will also return false for the 1st one too.

Can someone explain to me why PHP does this, and maybe a fix for this? (I am running PHP 5.4.22)

Basically what I want to accomplish is `isInt("4")` to echo true, `isInt(4)` to echo true, and `isInt("Text")` to echo false;

Comment: That's just the way PHP "works". `==` type juggles its operands, even with explicit casting.

Comment: use is_numeric() instead no need for custom function then

Comment: You think that's bad? Try `$a = '0xFF'; $b = '255.0'; var_dump($a == $b)` ...

Comment: Why don't you use is_int() function? http://php.net/is_int

Comment: PHP can be really annoying at times. Thanks Dave, that works for what I need. Mario, I don't think `is_int()` will work in my case, whereas `is_numeric()` is much more flexible

Comment: Question: do you expect to receive `true` or `false` for these inputs: `'0x25'`, `'020'`, `'25e3'` ? `is_numeric` will happily accept those, which, when dealing with user input, might have side-effects.

Comment: I won't really be dealing with user input, basically I'll be dealing with regular numbers, which I don't know if they will be in quotes or not, and then also text which will be like "SMSGL" and "NC3BRU" and other similar text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the triple equals, it checks the type along with the result.

For the first one, "4" is a string, not an int (the literal 4 is an int, but since you're using quotes, it's a string).

For the second one, "Test" is a string as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your second version:

```
$id = 'Test';
'Test' == (int)'Test';
'Test' == 0
0 == 0
TRUE
```

Strings which contain no digits at the beginning of the string will always get auto-converted to integer 0 when used in an integer context.

If you'd had `123Test` instead:

```
$id = '123Test';
'Test' == int('Test');
'Test' == 123
0 == 123
FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

to get desired value , check this..

```
if($id === (int)$id)echo "True.<br />";
```